# Table in database not consistent with the entity schema

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine2 in my symfony2.8-based website to interact with the database. I created the table successfully using the command line tool (doctrine:schema:create).

But after running the command `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` and then `doctrine:schema:update --force`, I came to find out only the columns "id" and "name" had been created in my MySQL database.

I've checked the mapping data (annotations) on my entity and run the 2 latter commands again, but the table is still the same with the command line tool returning the message saying "Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata."

Any suggestions or remarks?

Please find below how my entity look like:

```
<?php
namespace MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Contact
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="contact")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MainBundle\Repository\ContactRepository")
 */
class Contact
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(length=100)
     * @Assert\Length(max="100")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your email address")
     * @Assert\Email(checkMX=true, message="Please check the email you've provided")
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string")
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/^\+?[\d]+$/", message="Please check the phone info you've provided")
     * @Assert\Length(max="40")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter a phone number")
     * @ORM\Column(name="phone", length=40)
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter a message")
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="message", type="text")
     */
    private $message;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->date = new \DateTime();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     *
     * @return Contact
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Contact
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return Contact
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set phone
     *
     * @param string $phone
     *
     * @return Contact
     */
    public function setPhone($phone)
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get phone
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPhone()
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    /**
     * Set message
     *
     * @param string $message
     *
     * @return Contact
     */
    public function setMessage($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get message
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMessage()
    {
        return $this->message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using any kind of doctrine metadata cache? Also try to merge two separate `Column` annotations on the email field.

Comment: Not at all, I have not change anything in Doctrine lib embedded in Symphony framework. I'll try to merge that, but why "phone" and "message" columns are not being created in the database?

Comment: Try to clear the cache manually by deleting cache/* folders.

Comment: I've just tried again, but I'm still having the same message: "Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata."

Comment: Make sure that you check the correct database.

Comment: I have only one database so far

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to get around this issue by creating my table manually, then after generating my entity from my existing database as explained here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html